# How do the parameters of args AND kargs both look in Python?

Tags: python, function, args

I suppose I understand how to use them individually in functions like ...

f(*args) or f(**kargs)

But what if a function accepts both as arguments?
Ex: f(*args, **kargs)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works

```
def f(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

If you call function like this `f(1, 3, "foo", [1, 2, 10], a=1, apple=33)`, then in function `args` will be `(1, 3, "foo", [1, 2, 10])`, `kwargs` will be`{'a': 1, 'apple': 33}`.

It will work too

```
def f(a, b, foo, *args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

But if we call this function with the same arguments, `a` will be `1`, `b` will be `3`, `foo` will be `"foo"`, `args` will be `([1, 2, 10])`, `kwargs` will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

`*args` gets positional arguments; `**kwargs` gets named arguments. For instance:

```
f(1, 2, 3, a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

would pass

```
args = (1, 2, 3)
kwargs = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```